# passing a slice/array to another struct

Tags: go

I have the following code that works for me.

```
params := &cloudformation.CreateStackInput{
    StackName:   aws.String(d.MachineName),
    TemplateURL: aws.String(d.CloudFormationURL),
    Parameters: []*cloudformation.Parameter{
        {
            ParameterKey:   aws.String("KeyName"),
            ParameterValue: aws.String(d.KeyPairName),
        },
    },
}
```

I would like to externalize the creation of the Parameters,  so I have created the following method.

```
func (d *Driver) createParams() []cloudformation.Parameter {

val := "KeyName=Foo|KeyName2=bar"

s := strings.Split(val, "|")

a := []cloudformation.Parameter{}

for _, element := range s {

    pairs := strings.Split(element, "=")

    key := pairs[0]
    value := pairs[1]

    par := cloudformation.Parameter{
        ParameterKey:   aws.String(key),
        ParameterValue: aws.String(value),
    }

    a = append(a, par)

}

return a
```

}

My issue is how to I pass the output of createParams to the Parameters from CreateStackInput?

```
params := &cloudformation.CreateStackInput{
    StackName:   aws.String(d.MachineName),
    TemplateURL: aws.String(d.CloudFormationURL),
    Parameters:  d.createParam(),
}
```

The above yields

```
cannot use d.createParam() (type []cloudformation.Parameter) as type []*cloudformation.Parameter in field value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointer types are not compatible with the dereferenced types they point to, the error is telling you this very thing as you are trying to set a `[]*cloudformation.Parameter` to a `[]cloudformation.Parameter`.  Change the return type of `createParams` to `[]*cloudformation.Parameter` and set `par := &cloudformation.Parameter`.

```
func (d *Driver) createParams() []*cloudformation.Parameter {
  val := "KeyName=Foo|KeyName2=bar"
  s := strings.Split(val, "|")
  a := []*cloudformation.Parameter{} //a should be a slice of pointers
  for _, element := range s {
      pairs := strings.Split(element, "=")
      key := pairs[0]
      value := pairs[1]
      par := &cloudformation.Parameter{ //& turns par into a pointer to the parameter
          ParameterKey:   aws.String(key),
          ParameterValue: aws.String(value),
      }
      a = append(a, par)
    }
  return a
  }
```

Comment: While that is the correct answer,  can you provide some explanation

Comment: I added some more context to my answer, but the gist is []cloudformation.Parameters as a type != []*cloudformation.Parameters as a type.